# XSP2 crashes serving static images

Tags: mono, xsp2

Requesting a simple HTML page with a jpg image makes XSP2 crash. If I remove the image from the HTML then the page is served OK all the time.

The version is XSP2 2.0 mono 2.6.1. the version 2.4.2.2 in the same machine works fine.

I have tested it in two different machines, both Windows Vista Business SP1.

Anyone has experienced the same? Any clue of what can be the problem?

Below is the stack trace displayed by the console: (The line in Spanish says "it has been forced the interruption of an existing connection by the remote host")

**EDIT:**

since another user is having the same problem I have submited a bug to Novell and created a litle zip to reproduce the problem: https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=582162

```
Peer unexpectedly closed the connection on write. Closing our end.
System.IO.IOException: Write failure ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Se
 ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto.

  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send (System.Byte[] buf, Int32 offset, Int32 size
, SocketFlags flags) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
 Int32 size) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
 Int32 size) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.WebServer.XSPWorker.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 position, Int32
 size) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
Peer unexpectedly closed the connection on write. Closing our end.
System.ObjectDisposedException: The object was used after being disposed.
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.CheckDisposed () [0x00000] in <filename un
known>:0
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
 Int32 size) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.WebServer.XSPWorker.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 position, Int32
 size) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been fixed and it will be featured in version 2.6.5:

https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=582162#c7

**Update**: Here is the [latest bug free windows version](http://go-mono.com/monotools-download/latest/mono-windows.exe).

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem... I think that problem is in thread safety... Tracks lead to  _wapi_send call at mono/mono/metadata/socket-io.c. Definitely exception raises in native code. And i think it's nothing special about Mono 2.4.2... I looked through sources and all of them (spoted) are same in both versions.
My tests shown that sometimes it xsp crashes because of loading js, and even because of contineous-Ctrl-F5 of an empty html (like );
But if to laod pages with higher interval the probability of crash lowers...

Comment: Thats extrange because I tested with 2.4 and couldn't make it crash.

Comment: I've found a solution for my task. The solution is not to use XSP but to use Cassini: http://www.asp.net/Downloads/archived/cassini/ for a while and then to develop my own HTTP-server. Unfortunately Cassini (by the way Visual Studio uses it as a development server) is slow and wasn't developed for high-load =)

Comment: Hi ILya, does you own server works better that Cassini? If so, will you share it?

Comment: Hi, Dawkins... I have no my own server yet... It's still a future task. Now we'are using Cassini and it's enough for a while... I hope, Novell will fix XSP2 soon so we could use it...